# c++ run curl in shell via system

Tags: c++, shell, curl

If I write this in my shell, everything works like a charme:

```
// shell (unix)
curl -X PUT -d "{ \"string\" : \"my string 1212 \"}" "https://my.firebaseio.com/myVal.json"
```

As you can tell, this inserts some stuff in my `firebase`. As mentioned above, this works as expected. Since I am not too deep in C++, I have no idea on how to PUT `curl`-requests internally. I was thinking about doing it in the shell via `system`.

I ended up with this:

```
// c++ code
system('curl -X PUT -d "{ \"string\" : \"my string 1212 \"}" "https://my.firebaseio.com/myVal.json" ');
```

This however produces this output:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: CD
curl: (7) Could not resolve host: CD
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

Thanks for any helpful advices

// Update 1

After hearing that single quotes `'` are reserved for chars and going for the solution erip provided, it is still the same output:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cd
curl: (7) Could not resolve host: cd
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
{
   "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names."
}
```

Comment: Your C++ code wouldn't compile. You can't use single-quotes for c-strings in C++.

Comment: Any reason you're not invoking the API directly with libcurl? http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: @DaoWen as mentioned, not too deep into C++. Do I just have to place the lib in some specific folder and include it via #include <curl> or something?

Comment: You'd have to #include the header, _and_ link the library when you compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, single quotes are used for the type `char`. Double quotes are reserved for `std::string`s or `char *`s.

Thus, your solution should be by simply replacing single quotes with double quotes and escaping the quotes that aren't your final quote:

```
system("curl -X PUT -d \"{ \"string\" : \"my string 1212 \"}\" https://my.firebaseio.com/myVal.json ");
```

However, like @DaoWen mentioned, always use a library if/when possible.

**EDIT**

I'd recommend trying this:

```
std::string command = "curl -X PUT -d \"{ \"string\" : \"my string 1212 \"}\" https://my.firebaseio.com/myVal.json ";

system(command.c_str());
```

But honestly, it's better to use `fork` and `exec` calls than system calls if you don't want to use `libcurl`.

**EDIT 2**

```
std::string command = "curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X PUT -d '{ \"string\" : \"my string 1212 \"}' https://my.firebaseio.com/myVal.json";

system(command.c_str());
```

The weird escaped quotes were treating key: "string"  as the host because `{` was surrounded by quotes, acting as the data. I fixed this by surrounding the data to be passed with a single quote.

You can see that I `PUT` `{ "Hello" : "World!" }` to your app [here](https://my.firebaseio.com/myVal.json).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Still the same Issue:
I'll update the question for the indends

Comment: @erip You're missing a few backslashes there.  The argument to `-d` needs to be doubly-escaped.  Once for the shell (as the OP did), and once more for C++.